# Is it possible to replay Akka Persistence Journal on all Actors?

Tags: akka, event-sourcing, akka-persistence

I have an Akka Persistence Journal and several databases serving different views on the data saved in the journal. Most of the views include multiple entities ( -> multiple Persistent Actors ).

I understand that I can trigger recovery for one actor, which would rebuild the views consisting of only that entity, but in case I want to rebuild all views, how would I go about this?

I could startup all existing actors (for which I would need to know all of them) to trigger recovery of the whole system, but is there a way to give a Journal to an Actor System and basically tell it to replay the whole thing?

Answer (score 1):

With Akka Persistence Query you can do

```
readJournal.allPersistenceIds()
```

and start up all actors using the persistence ids, which would trigger recovery..